# Core Data migration failing with error: Failed to save new store after first pass of migration

Tags: iphone, core-data, mapping-model

In the past I had already implemented successfully automatic migration from version 1 of my data model to version 2. Now, using SDK 3.1.3, migrating from version 2 to version 3 fails with the following error:

**Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 UserInfo=0x5363360 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)", {
    NSUnderlyingError = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 UserInfo=0x53622b0 "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)";
    reason = "Failed to save new store after first pass of migration.";
}**

I have tried automatic migration using `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` and also migration using only `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption`, providing a mapping model from v2 to v3.

I see the above error logged, and no object is available in the application. However, if I quit the application and reopen it, everything is in place and working.

The Core Data methods I am using are the following ones

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }



    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MYAPP" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

    return managedObjectModel;

}
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }


    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}



- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MYAPP.sqlite"]];


  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

  NSError *error = nil;
  persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
   if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   }  


return persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

In the simulator, I see that this generates a MYAPP~.sqlite files and a MYAPP.sqlite file. I tried to remove the MYAPP~.sqlite file, but

```
BOOL oldExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MYAPP~.sqlite"]];
```

always returns NO. Any clue? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am now seeing the same issue exactly, error 134110 that is, on first launch it doesn't load correctly and on subsequent launches it does - only on 3.1.3.  Very bad user experience for the customer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well and after reading as much Apple docs and web postings as I could find there didn't seem to be an answer.  In my case the manual migration was working as well but when I went to open up a new coordinator it would give the same error you had.  I finally decided to go back to my last working version of the data model and do a series of small changes/versions and see where it broke the auto-migration capabilities to drill further into it and it turned out it didn't. Now I can add entities, attributes and relationships without issue and they auto-migrate.  Any chance you deleted an interim version of the datamodel?

Comment: No, I just moved from v2 to v3 of my data model. In the process I added two entities, removed an entity and added some attributes and a relation to an entity. Your suggestion to arrive to my final v3 data model incrementally is worth trying. I will experiment adding things one at a time and see if this works.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the Magical Record Core Data utility package includes this hack:

```
[coordinator MR_addAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:storeFileName];

//HACK: lame solution to fix automigration error "Migration failed after first pass"
if ([[coordinator persistentStores] count] == 0) 
{
    [coordinator performSelector:@selector(MR_addAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:) withObject:storeFileName afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

You might try something similar.  I have been unable to find an explanation of what the problem is, though, or why just retrying it would work.